# Autolayout with hide/show tab bar animation in iOS7

Tags: animation, ios7, autolayout, show-hide, uitabbar

I am trying to achieve an show/hide tab bar effect and the content will be extended to fill the space where the tab bar used to be.

I found the code for show/hide tab bar and i am satisfied with it (source :http://www.developers-life.com/hide-uitabbarcontrolleruitabbar-with-animation.html)

i added the following code to position my button accordingly:

```
    if (hiddenTabBar) {

    self.constraintToBottom.constant=0;
    [self.TestButton setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
} else {
    self.constraintToBottom.constant=-49;
    [self.TestButton setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

}
[self.TestButton layoutIfNeeded];
```

and it works as expected. Except for the animation of the button. This is the initial screen of the app before animation:

[image: Before animation]

and this is after animation

[image: After animation]

i can successfully hide the tab bar and position the button with the correct animation. However when i want to show the tab bar again, the button seem to start from the bottom(outside) of the screen instead of the position as shown in the second diagram. I've adjust the animation time so that i can capture the screen while animating :

[image: Weird thing happen when i show it again]

the following is my full code for hide/show tab bar action

```
- (IBAction)TestTapped:(id)sender {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
if(hiddenTabBar)
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:60];
else
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
{
    CGRect _rect = view.frame;
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        if (hiddenTabBar) {

            _rect.origin.y = 431;
            [view setFrame:_rect];


        } else {
            _rect.origin.y = 480;
            [view setFrame:_rect];

        }
    } else if(view==self.TestButton)
    {
        NSLog(@"ZZ");
    }
    else{
        if (hiddenTabBar) {

            _rect.size.height = 431;
            [view setFrame:_rect];
        } else {
            _rect.size.height = 480;
            [view setFrame:_rect];

        }
    }

}
if (hiddenTabBar) {

    self.constraintToBottom.constant=0;
    [self.TestButton setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
} else {
    self.constraintToBottom.constant=-49;
    [self.TestButton setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

}
[self.TestButton layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView commitAnimations];
hiddenTabBar =!hiddenTabBar;
```

}

i would expect the animation of the button to start at the exact position of my second diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this category to hide/show tab bar with animation.

----------------------.h file---------------------

```
#define screenSize ([[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds])
@interface UITabBarController (HideTabBar)
- (void)hideTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)showTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)hideTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated complition:(void(^)())complition;

@end
```

----------------------.m file---------------------

```
#define kAnimationDuration .2
@implementation UITabBarController (HideTabBar)

- (void)hideTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated complition:(void(^)())complition
{
    CGRect statusbarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
    CGRect tabBarControllerFrame = self.view.frame;
    if (statusbarFrame.size.height>20)
    {
        tabBarControllerFrame.size.height =  screenSize.size.height + self.tabBar.frame.size.height - 20.0;
    }
    else
    {
        tabBarControllerFrame.size.height = screenSize.size.height + self.tabBar.frame.size.height ;
    }

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self.view setFrame:tabBarControllerFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (complition) {
                complition();
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.view setFrame:tabBarControllerFrame];
        if (complition) {
            complition();
        }
    }
}
- (void)hideTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self hideTabBarAnimated:animated complition:nil];
}

- (void)showTabBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect statusbarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
    CGRect tabBarControllerFrame = self.view.frame;
    if (statusbarFrame.size.height>20)
    {
        tabBarControllerFrame.size.height =  screenSize.size.height - 20.0;
    }
    else
    {
        tabBarControllerFrame.size.height = screenSize.size.height ;
    }

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self.view setFrame:tabBarControllerFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
    else
        [self.view setFrame:tabBarControllerFrame];
}
@end
```

---

Use as with your viewcontroller like.

```
[self.tabBarController hideTabBarAnimated:YES];//You can use completion handler if you want.
```

May be it would solve your problem.